# 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:1.0.1' breaks on clustering, :1.0.0 does not

Tags: android, google-maps, maps, cluster-manager

After upgrading `android-maps-utils` from `1.0.0` to `1.0.1` the cluster part of my app won't compile because

```
import com.google.maps.android.clustering.ClusterItem
import com.google.maps.android.clustering.ClusterManager
```

does not import anymore.

reverting to `1.0.0` it works again.

Do anyone know what breaking changes has been done in `1.0.1` ?

RG

Answer (score 0):

Try to clean project then invalidate cache /Restart.

Comment: Actually tried that, and error still persisted. I checked the GitHub repo, and the answer was there, there was a bug in the maven distribution. They have released v1.0.2 now, which fixed the problem. (I'll check my own answer above as real answer when I am allow in approx 12 hrs.)

Answer (score 0):

There was a bug in v1.0.1. v1.0.2 have recently been released, and that fixed it.